# Accessing left and right side indices in an array, where the elements differ by 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one-dimensional array like this:

```
data=np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,0,0,0])
```

With the function below, I am able to access the index pairs where the absolute difference between adjacent elements is 1.

Current code:

```
result = [(i, i + 1) for i in np.where(np.abs(np.diff(data)) == 1)[0]]
```

Current output:

```
[(3, 4), (8, 9), (20, 21)]
```

How would I modify this code so that for each place where the difference is 1, I get not only the pair of indices, but also two indices to the left and two to the right of the transition?

Required output:

```
[2,3,(3, 4),4,5,7,8,(8, 9),9,10,19,20, (20, 21),21,22]
```

Comment: What if a transition point is between the first two or last two elements? Should it just have one element before/after it? Or do you want some sort of placeholder, like `None` or `np.NaN`? I imagine you don't want invalid indices.

Comment: The transition is happens wherever the element values differece is 1. Its not one element before and after it, its like parameterized.  place holders are not required ,I just need the left and right of indices, where the element difference is 1.

Comment: I'll try to phrase my question differently. Consider `[5, 6, 6]`. The difference occurs at `(0, 1)`. There is only one index to the left. Do you want `[0, (0, 1), 1, 2]`?

Comment: Million thanks  for your time and your support. I got the required answers.

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] your question to state that invalid indices are okay in the output. Even though you've already got your answer, Stack Overflow questions and answers are a resource to future visitors. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my variable names. I didn't try to be professional. Also, this could probably be done in a "shorter" way. Just wanted to provide a solution.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,0,0,0])

result = [(i - 1, i, (i, i + 1), i + 1, i + 2) for i in np.where(np.abs(np.diff(data)) == 1)[0]]
new_result = []
for r in result:
    for r1 in r:
        new_result.append(r1)
new_result = np.array(new_result, dtype=object)

print(new_result)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, (3, 4), 4, 5, 7, 8, (8, 9), 9, 10, 19, 20, (20, 21), 21, 22]
```

Comment: Be aware that this could result in invalid indices. For example, the result from `[5, 5, 6]` would be `[0, 1, (1, 2), 2, 3]`, and `3` is not a valid index. (Your question doesn't specify what you want to happen in cases like this, so maybe that's fine.)

Comment: True, I used a case-specific approach. However, it also doesn't clarify if the indices have to exist within the list, or even what they mean for that matter.